# android- error with my scrollview

Tags: android, scrollview

I want to make a `ScrollView` which includes a `LinearLayout`:

```
    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="#000000" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainHolder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
    </ScrollView>
```

Now when i add children to *mainHolder* I cant scroll. whats wrong?

Comment: put ScrollView inside LinearLayout?!!!!!! why?

Comment: change orientation of ScrollView to vertical and you can not scroll becouse you does not have some item inside scroll view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ScrollView only supports vertical scrolling. For horizontal scrolling, use [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html).

Answer (score 1):

Adding a horizontal linear layout in a vertical scroll view is suspicious.

For horizontal, scrolling, use a [`HorizontalScrollView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html).

Also, `wrap_content` size in the scrolling direction is meaningless. If it really wrapped to content size, there would be no need to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

you are adding the child to the linear layout which is horizontal in orientation 
so it wrap the content horizontally

change the orientation of the linear layout to `vertical` or try [Horizontal Scrollview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html)

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainHolder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
```

Comment: but I want horizontal orientation

Comment: @Soheil so add the linear layout vertical orientation inside the horizontal oriented linear layout

Answer (score 0):

try this one

> ```
> <ScrollView
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_centerInParent="true"
>     android:background="#000000" >
> ```

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainHolder"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: This only adds one additional level to the view hierarchy without changing the OP's problem at all.